# Not getting results with datastore.GetAll in golang

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have two functions: one which writes entities to datastore and the other is suppose to retrieve them. When I use `datastore.GetAll()` function in my retrieval it returns no results. I do have a test that verifies that the writing seems to be working correctly. Any ideas as to why retrieval isn't working?

Here is the application code:

```
package tracker

import (
   "fmt"

   "appengine"
   "appengine/datastore"
)

type User struct {
    Email string
}

func createUser(ctx appengine.Context, email string) (*datastore.Key, error) {
    u := &User{
        Email: email,
        }
    incompleteKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "User", nil)
    key, err := datastore.Put(ctx, incompleteKey, u)
    if err != nil {
        return key, err
    }

    return key, nil
}

func getUser(ctx appengine.Context, email string) (u *User, e error) {
    users := []User{}
    q := datastore.NewQuery("User").Filter("Email", email)
    keys, err := q.GetAll(ctx, &users)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Printf("KEYS: %v", keys)
    return &users[0], nil
}
```

Here is the test code:

```
package tracker

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "appengine/datastore"
    "appengine/aetest"
)

// This test is passing.
func TestCreateUser(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, err := aetest.NewContext(nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer ctx.Close()

    email := "testing@testing.go"
    newKey, err := createUser(ctx, email)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Failed to create a new user: %v", err)
    }

    u := User{}
    datastore.Get(ctx, newKey, &u)

    if u.Email != email {
        t.Errorf("Expected email to be %s, found %v.", email, u.Email)
    }
}

func TestGetUser(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, err := aetest.NewContext(nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer ctx.Close()

    email := "testing@testing.go"
    newKey, err := createUser(ctx, email)
    fmt.Printf("key, %v; ", newKey)
    u, err := getUser(ctx, newKey)
    fmt.Printf("user, %v; error: %s", u, err)

    if u.Email != email {
        t.Error("Expected email to be %s, found %v.", email, u.Email)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datastore.GetAll()` doesn't return result to you because with that query **eventual consistency applies**. The SDK simulates the eventual consistency and doesn't return you the newly saved entities immediately.

But in your `TestCreateUser()` method when you use `datastore.Get()`, that will return you the entity even if it was newly ("just now") saved, because it's a lookup by a key, and they are **strongly consistent**.

What happens behind the scenes is that when you call `datastore.Put()`, the entity data (values of properties) is saved and its key is indexed, then `datastore.Put()` returns, and indices of other properties and composite indices are updated asynchronously "in the background". So if you try to execute a query that uses an index to find/list entities (you were querying by the `Email` property), that query will not see (will not include) new entities until they are properly indexed. When you do a `datastore.Get()`, that loads the entity by its key and not by other (non-key property or composite) indices, so getting an entity by key will see the new entity "immediately" (after `datastore.Put()` has returned).

If you want to test this in local environment, you may provide `StronglyConsistentDatastore` option when creating the instance that will be used to create a new context, like this:

```
inst, err := aetest.NewInstance(&aetest.Options{StronglyConsistentDatastore: true})
if err != nil {
    t.Fatalf("Failed to create instance: %v", err)
}
defer inst.Close()

req, err := inst.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatalf("Failed to create req: %v", err)
}
ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)
```

Also note that if you use a sleep (e.g. `time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)`), `datastore.GetAll()` will also return the new entity, but the above option is the proper way to test this.

There are numerous similar questions (+answers), read them for more details:

[Google App Engine Datastore - Testing Queries fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590519/google-app-engine-datastore-testing-queries-fails)

[How to filter a GAE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228712/how-to-filter-a-gae-query)

[Google app engine datastore query with cursor won't iterate all items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503343/google-app-engine-datastore-query-with-cursor-wont-iterate-all-items)

Comment: @katkinson Since it worked, the appropriate thing to do is mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it on the left.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  This let's future readers know that the answer solved the problem.